# Firebase Analytics Filter option not available

Tags: firebase, filter, firebase-analytics

Previously firebase analytics has Filter option, but now its not visible what is the issue. I was able to filter events on the basis of custom dimenssions and custom parameters. But now filter option is not visible.

Please help in this regard.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Analytics dashboard in Firebase has recently been updated with some Google Analytics 4 features which includes something called 'Comparisons' which replaces the previous Filters functionality. You should find that these are functionally the same, and you'll be able to use Comparisons just like you would use Filters.

In this case, you would first go into the Analytics dashboard and create and apply a Comparison (matching the same dimensions + parameters filtering conditions you would have created previously). From there, you can scroll down to the Events card in the main Analytics dashboard and click into any events that you want to compare based on the comparison group. Note that with comparisons, you can also add up to 5 comparison groups at the same time (as opposed to only filtering with one set of criteria at a time using Filters).